# "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?"

Tags: android, api, drive

So i just downloaded the Drive Api example in Git to get an easy introduction to Drive, but it didn't work with the original and unmodified code. Keeps throwing me the same message all the time: 
"Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?"

This message its the same even if i retrieve, query or list content. I looked for this question in some posts but i can't found a solution to this particular problem. Any help would be apreciated!

```
    public class QueryFilesInFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private ListView mResultsListView;
    private ResultsAdapter mResultsAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
        mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
        mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
                .setResultCallback(idCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
                return;
            }
            DriveId driveId = result.getDriveId();
            DriveFolder folder = driveId.asDriveFolder();
            Query query = new Query.Builder()
                    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "Filmoteca"))
                    .build();
            folder.queryChildren(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
                    .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new
            ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
                return;
            }
            mResultsAdapter.clear();
            mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
            showMessage("Successfully listed files.");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and in fact it was pretty obvious but this get me crazy for a week!

For getting a fix for this problem, you should Sign In with a GoogleApiClient first (you can use the demo in the Developers main page or github), then yo need to specify an ID for the file you want to access.
Next, you'll be able to query,retrieve, or do whatever you want with the Drive Api. Althought i think its an API a bit complicated to get started with and require some patience.

Tip: dont get mad if you erase a file manually in your Drive acount and still see it in your app, Drive does not sincronize till 10 or 15 minutes and maybe there is a way to force the sincronyze but i haven't find it.